# What does FSelector information.gain measure?

Tags: r

I am trying to understand how to properly use the R package FSelector, and in particular, its information.gain function.  [According to the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf):

```
information gain = H(class) + H(attribute) - H(class,attribute)
```

What do these quantities mean?  And how do they relate to the standard definition of Information Gain.  As far as I know, Information Gain due to an `attribute = H(S) - sum p(S_i)H(S_i)`  where `H(.)` is entropy; `S` is the unpartitioned set; `S_i` are the subsets of `S` induced by the attribute; and `p(S_i) = |S_i|/|S|`.

I would also like to know if there are any other packages that use the concept of Information Gain.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer on CV may be of your interest: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161429/why-would-perfectly-similar-data-have-0-mutual-information/161443#161443

Answer (score 9):

The idea behind FSelector and its functions is to choose the best combination of attributes found in a data set. Maybe, some attributes are unnecesary (maybe), that depends on the dataset you are dealing with.

information.gain is a function that select the best combination of attributes according to its "Information Gain". This functions is based on entropy (You can read a lot of docs about that).

Here is an example using the famous IRIS dataset (See the full example at http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=FSelector/man/information.gain.Rd&d=R_CC):

```
library(FSelector)
data(iris)

weights <- information.gain(Species~., iris)
print(weights)

subset <- cutoff.k(weights, 2)

f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "Species")
print(f)
```

That mean that the most important attributes are Petal.Width and Petal.Length

There are a lot of libraries using similar functions! (RWeka, CORElearn, FSelector...)

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to have a good attribute that has a low information gain?

Comment: Sure, you can use all attributes is you wish, but for some processes you just use the most representative ones. For example, in face recognition, you use only a subset of image's attributes; also, for compressing data. Maybe you can check the statistics and mathematics that lie behind all this. A good starting point is Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) or Principal Component Analysis. In short, you tend to use the attributes with the highest information gain ratio and leave those ones which have a low information gain.

Comment: @andresram1 PCA & SVD choose variables based on their variance, independently of their effect on the outcome. Information gain, on the contrary, ranks variables according to their ability to decrease "impurity" in the outcome. So, PCA and SVD are irrelevant here (at least at face value).